# Making a horse ride-able by only one player in vanilla Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I run a 100% Vanilla Minecraft server, and would like to have Undead Horses that only Moderators are able to use, but I'm not sure about how to do this. I've tried to use CustomName data tags when summoning the horse and then testing for players near the horse, but do not know how to kick the player off the horse if they do not match the correct UUID.

Comment: This is an interesting problem.  I hope there's a solution to it.

Comment: Fun discovery: Untamed horses with a saddle are fully rideable, but you can't access their inventory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The final bit that you need is to just teleport the non-mod player, like so: `tp @p ~ ~ ~` (of course, you're probably going to `execute` that command at the horse).  This works because the teleport moves the target, and everything that is riding it, but not the things that the target is riding.

But that's just the bit you were missing, my full solution is below.

---

First things first, you're going to have to give your mod horses custom names.  They can be unique, but it makes it easier if they're all the same.  For my example, I'll just use "Mod Horse".

Next, you'll need two scoreboard objectives, `isRiding` and `isMod`.  I have to admit that I don't really like having to use the `isMod` objective, but for my solution to work, it's unavoidable.

The final step is to have 4 command blocks triggered by a [20Hz fill clock](http://moesh.ca/clocks-in-minecraft-1-8/).  In order, those commands are:

```
scoreboard players add @a isMod 0
scoreboard players set @a isRiding 0
scoreboard players set @a isRiding 1 {Riding:{CustomName:"Mod Horse"}}
tp @a[score_isRiding_min=1,score_isMod=0] ~ ~ ~
```

The first command ensures that everyone always has a score in the `isMod` objective, the second and third commands reset the `isRiding` score, then set the score for anyone riding an entity named "Mod Horse" (this can be abused, by the way), and the fourth command teleports anyone riding a mod horse who isn't a mod to the same spot they were in, effectively knocking them off the horse.

Of course, you're also going to have to set the `isMod` score for all your mods, but that's easy with `/scoreboard players set <mod name> isMod 1`.

Comment: That is way easier than my idea of untaming them, setting temper to 0 and taking off the saddle...

Comment: Afaik, spaces in the name break DataTags, so you might want to change the name to "ModHorse".

Comment: Not if they're in quotes.  It works for me.

Comment: I already had the `Mod` objective on my server so as to display a list of moderators. So that's no issue! I'm testing the solution now.

Comment: This seems to not work, but I'm not exactly sure if it is simply an issue with my setup. What exactly do you mean by "in order"?

Comment: Fill clocks have a well defined order for triggering command blocks.  **Do not use redstone dust for triggering command blocks!** It doesn't (always) work.  I orient my fill clocks in the x (easterly) direction.  Then, I generally have all my triggered command blocks in a line with the same y and z coordinate, and the order they are executed is from low x to high x.  An important thing to note is that if you do not have a score in the `isMod` objective, you'll be able to ride a mod horse.  That's why I have the first scoreboard command.

Comment: @MBraedley I had forgotten to give myself a score when testing, haha. Thank you for the answer!

Comment: @MBraedley Not sure if you know or not, but can Skeletal/Zombie horses have usable chest inventory yet? Or is the chest function not implemented on them?

Comment: I don't know, but my guess would be no.  AFAIK, chest inventory is only available for donkeys and mules.  The wiki seems to agree with this.